# Cart coding help

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I've made a simple Javascript code for a shopping basket but now I have realised that I have made a error with making it and don't know how to fix it. What I have is a HTML file with the Javascript, but in the Javascript I have included the images source and fields that would normally only be in the HTML file but What I am trying to do now is make 2 files one a .HTML file and another .JS file, but what I want is only one button that adds to cart in the HTML file.

At the moment its has a button next to each item and then a button at the bottom. I need to get rid of the buttons next the item but I'm confused on how to do that, also I need the images sourced from the HTML file as well as the drop down boxes, but this is also in the javascript which I don't want.

This is my javascript file with the Javascript embedded in it. I have sourced it correctly in my HTML.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var items=['Xbox~149.99','StuffedGizmo~19.98','GadgetyGoop~9.97'];

var M='�';  var product=[]; var price=[]; var stuff='';

function wpf(product,price){var pf='<form><FIELDSET><LEGEND>'+product+'</LEGEND>';
pf+='<img src="../images/'+product+'.jpg"  alt="'+product+'" ><p>price           '+M+''+price+'</p> <b>Qty</b><SELECT>';
for(i=0;i<6;i++){pf+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'} pf+='</SELECT>';
pf+='<input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="cart()" /></FIELDSET></form>';
return pf
}

for(j=0;j<items.length;j++){
product[j]=items[j].substring(0,items[j].indexOf('~'));
price[j]=items[j].substring(items[j].indexOf('~')+1,items[j].length);
stuff+=''+wpf(product[j],price[j])+'';
}
 document.getElementById('products').innerHTML=stuff;

function cart(){ var order=[]; var tot=0
for(o=0,k=0;o<document.forms.length;o++){
if(document.forms[o].elements[1].value!=0){
qnty=document.forms[o].elements[1].value;
order[k]=''+product[o]+'_'+qnty+'*'+price[o]+'';
tot+=qnty*price[o];k++
}
}
document.getElementById('inCart').innerHTML=order.join('<br>')+'<h3>Total   '+tot+'</h3>';
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Does this make sense? I'm not sure If I've explained myself correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: Well I want a HTML file where I have the image source with the price and quantity drop down box, but I don't know how to do that as all of it in already in the javascript but I don't want that. I just need the javascript to call on the functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with shopping cart in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760838/help-with-shopping-cart-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is. There's a lot to be improved, but it works.

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Shopping</TITLE>
    <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <STYLE type=text/CSS>
        fieldset    {width:300px}
        legend      {font-size:24px;font-family:comic sans ms;color:#004455}
    </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY scroll="auto">
    <div id="products"></div><hr>
    <div id="inCart"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Add to cart" onclick="cart()" />
</BODY>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="cart.js"></SCRIPT>
</HTML>
```

Javascript File:

```
var items =
    [
        {'id':1, 'name':'Xbox',             'desc':'The best gaming console from Microsoft',    'price':149.99,     'image_src': '',    'qty':0},
        {'id':2, 'name':'Stuffed Gizmo', 'desc':'This gizmo is stuffed with stuff',             'price':19.98,  'image_src': '',    'qty':0},
        {'id':3, 'name':'Gadgety Goop', 'desc':'',                                                      'price':9.00,       'image_src': '',    'qty':0}
    ];

var M = '£';
var stuff = '';
var order = [];
var tot = 0;

for(j=0;j<items.length;j++) {
    stuff+=''+wpf(j)+'';
}
document.getElementById('products').innerHTML=stuff;

function wpf(j) {
    var pf='';

    pf+='<form name="frm_cart_'+j+'">';
    pf+='<fieldset><legend>'+items[j].name+'</legend>';
    pf+='<img src="../images/'+items[j].image_src+'"  alt="Image of '+items[j].name+'" >';
    pf+='<p>'+items[j].desc+'</p>';
    pf+='<p>Price:'+M+''+items[j].price+'</p>';
    pf+='<b>Qty</b>';
    pf+='<select id="qty_'+j+'">';
    for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
        pf+='<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>'
    }
    pf+='</select>';
    pf+='</fieldset>';
    pf+='</form>';
    return pf;
}

function cart() {
    var sel_elems = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    k=0;
    for (i=0; i < sel_elems.length; i++) {
        if (sel_elems[i].id.substring(0, 4) == 'qty_' && sel_elems[i].value > 0) {
            console.log(i, sel_elems[i].value);
            order[k]=''+items[i].name+'_'+sel_elems[i].value+'*'+items[i].price+'';
            tot += sel_elems[i].value*items[i].price;
            k++;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('inCart').innerHTML=order.join('<br>')+'<h3>Total   '+tot+'</h3>';
}
```

Comment: hmmm Doesn't seem to work when I click on add to cart. I tried to find the error but can't see anything?

Comment: What kind of browser do you use?
I tried it of Firefox 3.6 and Chromium (I'm on Linux) and it works perfectly.

Can you see if there are any errors in Firebug or in JS console?

Answer (score 0):

Have you referenced the JS files in your HTML?

Comment: No because that is my HTML file with the Javascript in it

Answer (score 0):

The most common error when dealing with external javascript for the first time is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"/>
```

In this case, that's invalid.  Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the javascript in a separate file, i.e. cart.js

Then, *after* the  tag, put this statement:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="cart.js"></SCRIPT>
```

It works on my end.

Comment: Yeah but I want to change it so that I have only one Add to cart button, at the moment I have an add to cart next to each item